# multi master two Mariadb databse in same server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have a critical and huge mariadb Database , but there is two kind of user who get query of database . i wanna make copy of that database , then make internal cluster and replicate them as master/master .
which solotion in better ? galera or what ? i couldn't find good document about that . 
i read this :
[https://mariadb.com/blog/high-availability-multi-source-replication-mariadb-100] but i wanna 2 database in one server !
what's you suggestion dudes ?

Comment: Using same DB server, save it into another database name, doesn't give you any advantages on I/O performance. You just waste the disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Is the other copy intended solely for backup?

Comment: it's not only for backup . i wanna make it safe . when very huge query ordered , database might damage . i wanna prevent that .

Comment: The damage is simply propagated to the other Master.

Answer (score -1):

Well I use MariaDB with MySql master/slave replication, but it's possible generate multi master with mysql replication, its easy to install and configurate.
I will leave you a link show step for step how do. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication.

Comment: Link-only answer are discouraged here on StackOverflow, please read more about **[how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)** questions on our site.